# How do I filter child collection in this LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have this query in LINQ where I retrieve values from parent/child/child entities.

```
  var _cpResults = (await _context.QualityCaseResult
            .Where(q => q.QualityCaseId == model.QualityCaseId
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductionNumber) || q.ProductionNumber.Contains(model.ProductionNumber)) 
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.OrderNumber) || q.OrderNumber.Contains(model.OrderNumber)))
            .Include(c => c.ControlPointResults)
                .ThenInclude(f => f.FormulaResults)
            .Include(c => c.ControlPointResults)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Images.Where(x => x.IsUploaded))
            .Where(qcr => (qcr.ControlPointResults
                .Any(cpr => (cpr.ControlPointId == model.ControlPointId)
                    && cpr.ProcessingDate > model.StartDate && qcr.ProcessingDate < model.EndDate
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultRecipe) || cpr.ResultRecipe == Convert.ToBoolean(model.ResultRecipe)) // todo: convert to boolean in blazor app instead
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PartNumber) || cpr.PartNumber.Contains(model.PartNumber))
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultOperator) || cpr.ResultOperator.Contains(model.ResultOperator)))))
            .Take(VVSConstants.SearchQualityCaseResultLimit)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync());
```

This is the request model:

```
   public class QualityCaseResultSearchParameters
{
public string StationId { get; set; }
public string QualityCaseId { get; set; }
public string ControlPointId { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public string ProductionNumber { get; set; }
public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
public string PartNumber { get; set; }
public string ResultRecipe { get; set; }
public string ResultOperator { get; set; }
}
```

The query is "almost" working except for this line:

```
 .Where(qcr => (qcr.ControlPointResults
                .Any(cpr => (cpr.ControlPointId == model.ControlPointId)
```

The Any is only checking if the conditions are met but what I need is getting the data based on the ControlPointId
The query returns all ControlPints under the parent QualityCaseResult

This is the return model:

```
public class QualityCaseResultModelForSearchResult : QualityCaseResultOverviewModel
```

{
public QualityCaseResultModelForSearchResult() { }

```
public QualityCaseResultModelForSearchResult(
    string id,
    DateTime processingDate,
    float processingTime,
    string productionNumber,
    string orderNumber,
    string status,
    string qualityCaseId,
    ICollection<ControlPointResultModelWithImagesAndFormulas> controlPointResults) : base(
        id: id,
        processingDate: processingDate,
        processingTime: processingTime,
        productionNumber: productionNumber,
        orderNumber: orderNumber,
        status: status,
        qualityCaseId: qualityCaseId)
{
    ControlPointResults = controlPointResults;
}
public ICollection<ControlPointResultModelWithImagesAndFormulas> ControlPointResults { get; set; }
```

}

I am rather new to LINQ and would appriciate a push in the correct direction

Current query status with this error:

The LINQ expression 'c' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync

```
      var _cpResults = await _context.QualityCaseResult
          .Where(q => q.QualityCaseId == model.QualityCaseId
             && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductionNumber) || q.ProductionNumber.Contains(model.ProductionNumber))
             && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.OrderNumber) || q.OrderNumber.Contains(model.OrderNumber)))
          .Include(c => c.ControlPointResults
          .Where(pr => pr.ControlPointId == model.ControlPointId
            && c.ProcessingDate > model.StartDate
            && c.ProcessingDate < model.EndDate
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultRecipe) || pr.ResultRecipe == Convert.ToBoolean(model.ResultRecipe))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PartNumber) || pr.PartNumber.Contains(model.PartNumber))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultOperator) || pr.ResultOperator.Contains(model.ResultOperator))))
         .ThenInclude(f => f.FormulaResults)
         .Include(c => c.ControlPointResults
         .Where(pr => pr.ControlPointId == model.ControlPointId
            && c.ProcessingDate > model.StartDate
            && c.ProcessingDate < model.EndDate
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultRecipe) || pr.ResultRecipe == Convert.ToBoolean(model.ResultRecipe))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PartNumber) || pr.PartNumber.Contains(model.PartNumber))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultOperator) || pr.ResultOperator.Contains(model.ResultOperator))))
         .ThenInclude(i => i.Images.Where(x => x.IsUploaded))
         .Take(VVSConstants.SearchQualityCaseResultLimit)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I think you want .Contains instead of .Any

Comment: Can you post the actual sql EF is generating?

Comment: @GHDevOps If I change Any to Contains I get the following error

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1660?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1660)

Cannot convert lambda expression to type "ControlPointResult" since it is not a delegate type

Comment: I am not able to see the generated SQL. Does it matter that I am accessing the code trough Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking about filtering the resulting related data. This is something that is supported in EF Core so you have two options. Filtering the related data or filtering it during projection. (Where you populate your results object(s))

Filtering related entities:

```
.Include(c => c.ControlPointResults.Where(pr.ControlPointId == model.ControlPointId)
    && cpr.ProcessingDate > model.StartDate 
    && qcr.ProcessingDate < model.EndDate
    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultRecipe) 
        || cpr.ResultRecipe == Convert.ToBoolean(model.ResultRecipe)) 
    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PartNumber) 
        || cpr.PartNumber.Contains(model.PartNumber))
    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultOperator) 
        || cpr.ResultOperator.Contains(model.ResultOperator))))
    .ThenInclude(f => f.FormulaResults)
.Include(c => c.ControlPointResults.Where(pr.ControlPointId == model.ControlPointId)
    && cpr.ProcessingDate > model.StartDate 
    && qcr.ProcessingDate < model.EndDate
    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultRecipe) 
        || cpr.ResultRecipe == Convert.ToBoolean(model.ResultRecipe)) 
    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PartNumber) 
        || cpr.PartNumber.Contains(model.PartNumber))
    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResultOperator) 
        || cpr.ResultOperator.Contains(model.ResultOperator))))
    .ThenInclude(i => i.Images.Where(x => x.IsUploaded))
```

I'm not sure if the `Where` condition is needed on both `Incude`s in order to facilitate the multiple `ThenInclude` conditions. (My parenthesis might not line up) There also appeared to be a typo/error in your query where you were comparing the start date from the ControlPointResults (cpr.ProcessingDate > model.StartDate) but then the end date against the outer QualityCaseResult. (***qcr***.ProcessingDate < model.StartDate)

However, this should only include ControlPointResults for the matching ControlPointId.

I don't recommend returning entities or classes extending entities to serve as models for views. The main reasons for this is that you are often loading and sending far more data than you actually need. If you only need one or two fields from a particular related entity, it is better to have EF only fetch those one or two properties rather than eager loading the entire entity graph in order to provide them.

With an independent view model and projection, the alternative option is to filter the data at projection. This could be using `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` where Automapper is configured to filter the relevant child data. It is generally better to avoid embedding conditional checks within the Linq expression. This means checking for whether model.Value has a value inside the `Where`/`Any` clause and instead using an `if` outside of the clauses to append filter only if the condition is present. However, this can require some pretty complex expression building when composing more complex expressions involving inner funcs like `Any`.

Projection's advantage is that it avoids loading *everything* about the entity graph where the views likely only need a subset of fields. This can handle filtering out related entities, as well as just generally not loading everything about a related entity where the view might just need a few fields.

Comment: It looks like I am getting somewhere but I still have some error,, 
The LINQ expression 'c' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync 

I have added current query in the question above... not figuring out what the error is

Comment: ok, it may not like the Convert.ToBoolean. Pull that out before the query to something like `bool resultRecipe = Convert.ToBoolean(model.ResultRecipe);` then replace where it is used in the query expression with `resultRecipe`. 

Worst case simplify down a copy of the query to exclude the two eager joins and ensure it returns the data expected, then add one of the eager joins adding conditions one by one. This can help assess exactly what the builder is having issues with.